# Create a plane from a grid with geometry nodes

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I'm modelling a grill using geometry nodes and I want to intersect instance cylinders on a grid node with a plane to create the holes. I was thinking about using the grid node itself to generate the plane, but I can't find a simple way of doing it.

I ended up using "Points to Volume" + "Volume to Mesh" but that is just too convoluted. I see that there's a Cube node in the Mesh Primitives section, but no Plane.

Is there a better approach for creating a plane using geometry nodes?

Comment: A Grid _is_  a (superset of a) plane. You could create it with 2 verts X&Y if you need it without internal edges, and subdivide it further down the tree for instancing the cylinders, for example.

Comment: ah @RobinBetts so I could instead make the plane mesh first _then_ the grid out of it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this kind of setup if you don't want the overhead of using a boolean modifier with a very high number of cutting meshes :

[image]

It's instancing a simple plane and cutting it in the middle with a cylinder, then arraying it on another grid to create a grill.

You'll need to add a [Realize Instances](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/instances/realize_instances.html) node just before the group output if you want to use other modifiers afterwards :

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 nice!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: oh this is great!

Comment: interestingly, using the same setup as you I can't control the bevel offset, changing the Amount value doesn't affect the object...

Comment: Did you add the weld modifier ? If you don't it doesn't consider the individual pieces as connected and you the bevel doesn't work

Comment: @Gorgious I did... I'll revisit my file and check if there's anything else missing

Answer (score 5):

you can do it like this:

[image]

So i just used a boolean mesh node to cut out the cylinders, which were created by grid instancing cylinders.

[image]

Comment: that's a simple way of doing it!